openlitespeed access logs - time to serve the request
I have openlitespeed server that runs over QUIC.
I want to download file from the server, and get from the access logs of the server the time to serve the request (%D in the logs format).
In my case some of the files are very small - around 100 bytes.
For such small files I found that the request time can be very long, 100 millisecond which there is no reason for such long time, the RTT is around 30 millisec.
On the other have sometimes the request time can be supper short, less around 100 microsecond, and in this case, how can the request time be shorter than the the RTT?
Is there a good explanation for such behaviour?
I tried to find some documentation about the way openlitespeed or apache HTTP server calculates this metric with no success.
If there is some good documentation, I would be glad for a reference.

If the server logs the time of the request, it is very unlikely that network latency is included, isn't it? I would interpret "time to serve the request" at the time from receiving the request to (and including) sending the response.

In most cases, this in incorrect.
If you want to measure the time took the server to start send data (ttfb) you need to use %^FB flag. in most cases the response will require several packages, and it will take time to send them all, this time depends on the latency of the network. but in my case the file is very small - less than 1 package, so I'm not sure how it will handle it.

even if the time here does not includes the latency of the network, how come the range of serving time is so wide?

A possible explanation could be disk caching.
